# Converting Fortran IV to 77

Tags: fortran, converters

I am looking for a utility to convert fortran IV code to a more structured sort of fortran like fortran 77 or later. I am trying to understand what exactly the code does and all those "goto" and calculated "if" statements don't help.
Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity why do you need this?

Comment: How many lines of code are we talking here?

Answer (score 2):

All already mentioned aside, in the end it always comes down to a bit of *hard labour* :) And that's where [SciTools Understand](http://www.scitools.com/) shines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a section of the [FORTRAN FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/fortran-faq/) on this (search for "Code re-structurers and converters")

[TIDY](http://www.unb.ca/fredericton/science/chem/ajit/tidy/) looks like it will do some of the work for you. Unfortunately not including the calculated-if and goto

Web page last updated more than 10 years ago!

A [commercial product is here](http://www.crescentbaysoftware.com/vast_77to90.html), but costs ~$500 for 5000 lines of conversion.

Courses on how to do this manually [can be found here](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/OldFortran/)

[IBM utility to convert Fortran IV to PL-I :)](http://www.bighole.nl/pub/mirror/www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/360/fortran/GC33-2002-2_FORTRAN_To_PL1_Translator_Jan73.pdf) written in 1973, it seems

Answer (score 1):

There is also PlusFort, which can do comprehensive restructuring -- see the examples at http://www.polyhedron.com/spag0html.  There is a reduced capability version that is free for certain uses: http://www.polyhedron.com/pflinux0html